# datesDisabled Bootstrap-DatePicker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

There are plenty of questions on this but none of them seem to have worked for me.

I will eventually have an array of dates being passed in for multiple days over different months.

I'm using this version of the bootstrap datepicker
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

looking over the docs, a simple array of dates for'disabledDates' should be all it needs to get these working, but I'll be damned if it accepts it.

Any ideas as to why it doesn't work?

```
var disabledDates = ['28/3/2018','22/3/2018'];

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    maxViewMode: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    clearBtn: true,
    multidate: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
    datesDisabled: disabledDates
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `disabledDates` variable you used dates like `'28/3/2018'` and `'22/3/2018'`. According to the doc these dates are in this format `d/m/yyyy` or `dd/m/yyyy`.

But, inside `datepicker()` function you have declared the date format as `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Try to change the date format `format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',` to `format: 'd/m/yyyy',` or `format: 'dd/m/yyyy',`

Comment: Not working the way you have suggested, tried many combinations on the similar lines, but seems that disabledDates option is not working even in sandbox mode at https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=component&format=dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&todayHighlight=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on&datesDisabled=on#sandbox